# Delete trailing commas in line

Tags: sed

How do I delete a set of trailing commas in bash:

```
a,b,c,d,,,,
1,2,3,,,,
```

Desired Output:

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3
```

Tried doing this:

```
 grep "5628" test.csv | sed 's/,*$//g'
```

but it doesn't work. The file originally came from a Windows machine.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't work? What full command did you run?

Comment: Positive. It didn't.

Comment: Can you provide your exact command, please (the `sed` you've shown without a filename acts as a filter and does not process a file _in place_)

Comment: grep "5628" test.csv | sed 's/,*$//g'

Comment: Did this file `test.csv` originally come from a Windows or Mac machine?

Comment: well Original file came from windows machine, did awk and redirected it to test.csv

Comment: If you need to use the file in \*nix and you don't need to be able to copy it back to Windows, it might be easier in the long run to convert the line endings from CR/LF to NL with `dos2unix` or something like that.

Comment: @G-Man I didn't even think about the windows delimiters being issue. Was under the impression that somehow my syntax was messed up.

Comment: @user2980702:, No, `sed 's/,*$//g'` is fine — *unless* `sed` treats the carriage return (CR) as being "just another character" at the end of the line — so `1,2,3,,,,<CR>` would be treated the same as `1,2,3,,,,G`, for example.  In fact, `sed 's/,*$//g'` works fine in Cygwin **on a file with Windows line endings**, using GNU sed; it's not surprising that other versions of `sed` are less intuitive.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Re the command you have provided:

> ```
> grep "5628" test.csv | sed 's/,*$//g'
> ```

This will output lines matching '5628' with all trailing commas removed. It will not update the file `test.csv`.

However, you indicated the file came from a Windows machine, so the line endings are CR/NL instead of just NL. The result is that there is a hidden CR at the end of the line, and you need a command line this instead:

```
grep "5628" test.csv | sed 's/,*\r*$//'
```

Actually, you can simplify this to one command:

```
sed -n '/5628/s/,*\r*$//p' test.csv
```

Comment: I'm not trying to do in place update. Just need the output without commas

Comment: This worked Thank you so much. So we're looking for multiple commas (,*) before carriage return at the end of the file (\r*$). Am i right ?

Comment: The `\r*` allows for zero-or-more CR characters (so it will continue to work with Unix/Linux derived files). I'd prefer to use `\r?` to indicate a single optional CR but I couldn't remember the flag to `sed` to tell it to use EREs off the top of my head. I think it's `-r` but untested here. The `,*` is yours and matches zero-or-more commas.

Comment: the `g` is not needed in this case, ter is only 1 end specified by `$`

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n '/5628/ s/,*\r*$//p' test.csv
```

(not the OP that only ask to remove trailing coma) this avoid a piping process, sed taking directly the filter and the conversion